# encryption program with python. while loop out of bounds

Tags: python, encryption

code:

```
import random
randomnum = random.randint(0, 255)
enter = "a"
enterlen = (len(enter))
alphabetarray = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k"
                 "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v"
                 "w", "x", "y", "z"]

enterarray = ["", ""] + list(enter)
numarray = [""]
i = 0
r = 0




while i <= enterlen:
    i = i + 1
    while r <= 26:
        if enter[i + 2] == alphabetarray[r]:
            print("hi")
            numarray.append(1)
            print(numarray)


error: if enter[i + 2] == alphabetarray[r]:
IndexError: string index out of range
```

goal of code:The goal of the program is to take a string you give it (enter) and turn it into numbers(a = 1, b = 2, etc, etc). I have an array that is suppose to fill up with numbers depending on what is in enter.

problem: I think mynumarray is not "big" enough even though im appending it?

Comment: Remember that indexing (`[i]`) starts from zero. You can put some `print` statements in your program to examine how `i`, `r`, `enter`, and `numarray` change during the run.

Answer (score 0):

try this code ,
enterarray[i+2] == alphabetarray[r]